# Enemy is moving in a jittery way and I do not know how to solve this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am **new** to Unity and I was working on the enemy's movement of my first video game with C#.
The thing is that whenever the enemy follows the main character, it moves in a very jittery way and I do not know why. I tried a lot of solutions including a different code approach but notthing worked. I tried changing some configurations in its rigid body like collision detection but nothing happend.

This is the code of my enemy:
public class Black : Enemy
{

```
public float checkRadius;

public float attackRadius;

public bool shouldRotate;

public LayerMask lm;
private Rigidbody2D bd;
private Vector2 movement;
public Vector3 dir;
private bool isInchaseRange;
private bool isInattackRange;
// Start is called before the first frame update


void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Jugador " + player.name);
    bd = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    isInchaseRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, checkRadius, lm);
    isInattackRange = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, attackRadius, lm);
    dir = player.position - transform.position;
    dir.Normalize();
    movement = dir;
}
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (isInchaseRange && !isInattackRange) {
        MoveCharacter(movement);
    }
    if (isInattackRange)
    {
        bd.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

private void MoveCharacter(Vector2 dir) {
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

[image]

This is how I move my main character if it helps you

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private Vector2 moveAmount;

    public float health;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveAmount = moveInput.normalized * speed;
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        move();
    }

    void move()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        

    }

    public void takeDamage(int damageAmount)
    {
        health -= damageAmount;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The character has the same stuff as the enemy: Script, box collider 2d, rigid body
Any ideas on how to solve this?

As you can see by the gif it is not working as it should
https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-fbffacda5a27.gif

Thanks

Comment: What are you calculating the `dir` for and pass it into `MoveCharacter` if you don't use it anyway? In general do **not** Mix physics with movement vis the `Transform` component! Rather use e.g. `Rigidbody.MovePosition`

Comment: Thanlks for the response ! I was using the dir like this bd.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (dir * speed * Time.deltaTime)); in the movement funciont but it was still not working so I changed it to see if I could solve the problem in another way

Comment: Why don't you use s combination of the `Vector2.MoveTowards` and `MovePosition`? In general the issue is most probably that every frame you check whether you are in attack range .. so every fixed update you might just move enough to be outside that range again -> jitter .. I would use two ranges one for entering combat mode, one for leaving combat mode .. this way you should at least reduce this jitter s little bit

Comment: Thanks ! I am not the best at coding but I will still try this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try making the chase range huge and attack range very small and see if it still moves in a jittery way to make sure it's not jittering because it's going in and out of range very quickly.
2. Set Rigidbody2D to interpolate from the inspector.

Also for the player, use `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. Although this probably isn't related to your problem, this will give more smooth movement for the player. `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is just for setting the target you want the unity to stay at, but it will never precisely achieve that frametime. And `Time.deltaTime` will return the correct value based on whether it's called from `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`

> When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime. - [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Yes, it was still jittery with a huge chase range. I changed the velocity the enemy had from 20 to 5 and it improved a lot. It is still jittery though. https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-f06f0c4bc83c.gif

Comment: Changing the speed its just a "solution" for now